# How to i get original page parameters from jsp errorpage?

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, error-handling

I have an jsp/servlet webapp on tompcat and i need something like a crash report each time an unexpected error accords 
I have an error page defined and added with errorpage directive

```
<%@page errorPage="./erropage.jsp" %>
```

to my edit.jsp file(just an example).
The request to edit.jsp is made with post request (actually is an ajax request but this is not so important).
I need a solution to read original parameters (sent to edit.jsp page) from errorpage in order to buid a crash report.

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")
```

Doed not help me since this will include the actual url (get parameters).

Also, to build up a string from requested parameters in edit.jsp and set that string to session is not an option since there are to many files in witch i need to implement this.

Comment: did you try plain request.getParamter() from within error jsp.

Comment: In case of an error what will be your browser url? is it edit.jsp or is it redirected to error.jsp ? if it is redirected then there is no option to retrieve parameters

Comment: request.getParamter() in errorpage.jsp actually seams to work! Tx alot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seams like

```
request.getParamter()
```

in errorpage.jsp give the parameter from edit.jsp request!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with cookies and I post a question about it.
Now, I believe ( I have some checks to do) that the error mechanism is using REDIRECT scheme (not FORWARD) so a new request object is created.
. You can verify this assumption